# Automate a Button Click on a pop up

Tags: c#, service

I am planning to write a service to look for a pop op to appear and if the pop up does appear to click on the "OK" button. I have no experience in writing services or even how to look for a pop up. I am currently using AutoIT but would like to create something internally. I tried using Google but I think I am not asking a right question. Any ideas on the best approach or suggestions where to look of what to use?

Comment: Break this into two parts: first, find the window that you want to click OK on. Second, figure out how to click OK from your service. If you search for information on these, you'll turn up some good answers. You might also want to start with a desktop app before trying a service, as that will only complicate things at first.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Maybe what you are looking for is SendKey.

Comment: @Job B I appreciate that. I think I actually might have stumbled onto something http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22429/Windows-Service-which-Kills-Unwanted-Windows

Comment: @AlexMendez NO I have not tried anything as of yet just because I truthfully didn't know where to start. The link I found above might put me in the right direction.